# SQL injection error in Dynamic SQL with prepared statement

Tags: dynamic-sql, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I my application we are collection some user inputs from UI and based on those values we are generating dynamic SQLs with different 'Where' conditions to query data.
It is found that that piece of code has some SQL injection flaw.

```
public void filter(String strSerialNumberLogic, String strSerialNumber1,
            String strSerialNumber2, String strCreationDateLogic,
            long lngCreationDate1, long lngCreationDate2,
            String strTypeNumbers, String strTitles, long lngLoc)
            throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    StringBuffer strWhere = new StringBuffer();
    List paramList = new ArrayList();
    String arrTypeNumbers[];
    String arrTitles[];
    int i;
    boolean bolHit;

    if (!strTypeNumbers.equals("") || !strTitles.equals("")) {
        arrTypeNumbers = strTypeNumbers.split(",");
        arrTitles = strTitles.split(",");

        bolHit = false;
        strWhere.append("(");

        for (i = 0; i < arrTypeNumbers.length; i++) {
            if (arrTypeNumbers[i].length() > 0) {
                if (bolHit) {
                    strWhere.append(" OR ");
                } else {
                    bolHit = true;
                }

                strWhere.append(" REPORT_NUMBER = ?");
                paramList.add(arrTypeNumbers[i]);
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < arrTitles.length; i++) {
            if (arrTitles[i].length() > 0) {
                if (bolHit) {
                    strWhere.append(" OR ");
                } else {
                    bolHit = true;
                }

                strWhere.append(" REPORT_NAME = ?");
                paramList.add(arrTitles[i]);
            }
        }

        strWhere.append(") ");
    }

    if (!strSerialNumber1.equals("")) {

        if (!strWhere.equals("")) {
            strWhere.append(" AND ");
        }
        strWhere.append(" REPORT_FILE_NO " + strSerialNumberLogic + " ? ");
        paramList.add(strSerialNumber1);

        if (strSerialNumberLogic.equals("between")) {
            strWhere.append(" AND ? ");
            paramList.add(strSerialNumber2);
        }
    }

    if (lngCreationDate1 != 0) {


        if (!strWhere.equals("")) {
            strWhere.append(" AND ");
        }

        strWhere.append(" REPORT_CREATION_DATE " + strCreationDateLogic + " ? ");
        paramList.add(Long.toString(lngCreationDate1));

        if (strCreationDateLogic.equals("between")) {
            strWhere.append(" AND ? ");
            paramList.add(Long.toString(lngCreationDate2));
        }
    }

    if (lngLoc != 0) {

        if (!strWhere.equals("")) {
            strWhere.append(" AND ");
        }
        strWhere.append(" REPORT_FILE_LOCATION = ? ");
        paramList.add(Long.toString(lngLoc));
    }
    String finalQuery = "";
    if (!strWhere.equals("")) {
        finalQuery = "WHERE " + strWhere.toString();
    }

    String strSQL = "SELECT * " + "FROM D990800 "
            + "LEFT JOIN D990400 ON REPORT_SYSTEM_ID ||" + " REPORT_NO = REPORT_NUMBER " + finalQuery
            + "ORDER BY REPORT_FILE_NO ASC";


    System.out.println("strSQL:" + strSQL );
    System.out.println("paramList:" + paramList );

    Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.instance().getConnection();
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(strSQL);

    for (int index = 0; index < paramList.size(); index++) {
        String param = (String) paramList.get(index);

        if (isParsableInt(param)) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(index+1, Integer.parseInt(param));
        } else {
            preparedStatement.setString(index+1, param);
        }
    }

    ResultSet rsReports = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    buildCollection(rsReports);
    rsReports.close();
    preparedStatement.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I am not able to re arrange this code to prevent that flaw. Any suggestion will be helpfull.

My Application takes four input parameters ,

1. Serial number  -This can be, one or none, or two values
2.Created date -This can be, one or none, or two values
3. ReportTypeNumbers- This can be, one or none, or more than two
4. reportTitleNames-This can be, one or none, or more than two

based on these input values, I am constructing Dynamic 'Where' conditions for prepared statement.  This SQL has issues. Please help me to rewrite it to fix SQL injection flaw.

Comment: Any help is appreciated to rewrite this peice of code.

Comment: I don't see where SQL Injection is occurring.  You are already using BIND variables. How do you know you have SQL Injection?  Please modify your post to show "how you know you have SQL Injection" and add example input/resulting SQL-to-be-executed that proves you have SQL Injection.  (note: I see malformed SQL as "bad coding", not "SQL Injection)

Answer (score 0):

How did you come to the conclusion that you have SQL injection in this code? That would help clearing that up.
Anyway, looking at your code it seems that both `strSerialNumberLogic` and `strCreationDateLogic` are variables that comes from an external source, and are concatinated in a way that allows SQL to be injected. If this external source is the user, SQL injection can be executed. If not, than this is probably a false positive. I would improve the code anyway by chaning the logic variables turning them into Enums.